# How does MySQL determine the 'index first key' and 'index last key' with indexes?

Tags: mysql

In other words, how does MySQL find the result range with indexes on the first step when it's executing a select query?

Answer (score 1):

That is really the job of the MySQL Query Optimiser.  You can determine more information by evaluating the results of [EXPLAIN](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mysql%20explain&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html&ei=t4EzUarcCuTC0QW5_4HQBQ&usg=AFQjCNHldfPSw0MqKGJfCAjyYmlXfZ4rFQ).

You can also manually tweak the Query Optimiser by [forcing or hinting an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html), or changing the [optimizer_search_depth](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/controlling-optimizer.html) variable which will tell the Query Optimiser how far in the future of each incomplete plan the optimizer should look to evaluate whether it should be expanded.